# JScrollPane not scrolling horizontally

Tags: java, swing

I have a program I am working on and cannot figure out why it isn't scrolling horizontally. I have set the scroll policies for both hor and ver however only vertical scroll is showing up. The program gets a txt file that the user chooses and then displays it in the jtextarea. All is working fine except the horizontal scroll. Any ideas?

Thanks!

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

class FileChooserDemo3{

   JLabel jlab;
   JButton jbtnShow;
   JFileChooser jfc;
   JTextArea jta;
   JScrollPane scrollPane;
   String filename = null;

   FileChooserDemo3() {
      //create new JFrame container.
      JFrame jfrm = new JFrame("JFileChooser Demo");

      //Specify FlowLayout for layout manager
      jfrm.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

      //Give the frame initial size
      jfrm.setSize(800,800);

      //End program when user closes application
      jfrm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

      //Create a label to show selected file
      jlab=new JLabel();

      //Create button to show dialog
      jbtnShow = new JButton("Show File Chooser");

      //create textarea with ability to textwrap (p889-891) and scroll (hint:  Use JScrollPane)
      jta = new JTextArea(45, 40);
      jta.setLineWrap(true);
      JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(jta);






      //Create file chooser starting at default directory
      jfc=new JFileChooser();
      String name = null;
      //Show file chooser when show file chooser button pressed
      jbtnShow.addActionListener(new ActionListener()  {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent le) {
            //Pass null for the parent.  This centers the dialog on the screen.
            int result = jfc.showOpenDialog(null);

            if(result==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
               jlab.setText("Selected file is:  " + jfc.getSelectedFile().getName());
               File file = jfc.getSelectedFile();
               jfrm.add(scrollPane);
               scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(
         JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
      scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(
         JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
               jta.setText("");
               Scanner in = null;

               //Get selected file stored as a file.


               try{
                  //Do file processing here
                  in = new Scanner(file);
                  while(in.hasNext()) {
                     String line = in.nextLine();
                     jta.append(line+"\n");
                  }
               }

               catch(IOException e){
                  System.out.println("Exception");

               }
               finally {
                  in.close();
              }    



            }
            else{
               jlab.setText("No file selected.");
            }
         }
      });

         //add the show file chooser button and label to content pane
         jfrm.add(jbtnShow);
         jfrm.add(jlab);


         //Display the frame
         jfrm.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args){
      //Create GUI on the event dispatching thread.
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            new FileChooserDemo3();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn off line wrap for your JTextArea using `jta.setLineWrap(false);` instead of `jta.setLineWrap(true);`. Otherwise no horizontal scroll bar is needed because the JTextArea wraps the lines such that it fits into the parent without scrolling.

Comment: It isn't fitting without the scroll. It is still cutting off parts of the document to the right side when set to true. This is what's confusing me I guess. I can turn it off and the document will display with a lot of horizontal scroll.

Comment: Is the part cut off as wide as the vertical scrollbar?

Comment: Well, I guess what it is doing is just cutting words. For example if the line ends with the word "complete" it will show com then dump plete down to the next line. I think it should be okay for the assignment I guess I was just expecting it to behave more like regular text document.

Comment: `jta.setWrapStyleWord(true);`

Answer (score 3):

Remove the line wrap statement to allow the child component of the scrollbar to a have a horizontal size greater than the viewport size

```
jta.setLineWrap(true); // remove
```

Comment: That is strange. Did work however really messes up the look of the txt document. There is no way to have both text wrap and the scroll?

Comment: Nope, if it wraps then the derlying size will never exceed the viewport size width. Maybe you actually want to `setLineWrap(true)` and `jta.setWrapStyleWord(true)`